# delete avd emulator with mac

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am trying to delete multiple emulators manually.
The reason is because when I delete them from the avd manager, always indicates that the emulator is running .. not correct.
I am using a Mac, use the terminal and finder, but I can not find the folder where the emulator

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The emulator instances (AVDs) on OSX can be found in:

```
~/.android/avd
```

So, from a terminal:

```
cd ~/.android/avd
ls
```

will show you the emulators, and their configurations. Note that there is a .avd directory, as well as a .ini file for each emulator that exists.

Running:

```
rm -rf emulatorNameIWantToDelete.*
```

from the ~/.android/avd directory will manually remove that emulator.

Just be careful because the rm -rf command will delete something permanently.